# AS3 Combobox change dropdown position

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, combobox, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the position of the dropdown list relative to the combobox item.
Setting the position using comboBox.dropdown.x = 1337; doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Is this Flex 3 or Flex 4?

You can't just change stuff inside a component like that. You either need to subclass the ComboBox (Flex 3), or write a new skin (Flex 4).